# optimize and change style border vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I am creating a questionnaire and to be inserted in database. I'm doing Multiple Choices type. I am in a part where choosing a choices for a correct answer.

I wan't to change the border color of `choices inputs` if the `value is equal` to `correct input` and make `other border color black` if it's `not equal to correct input`,

but what happening to my code is, the border style of other choices that are not equal to the `correct input` stays greens, also my code is not so good i think there is a better way to make it much more clean and optimize.

This is what i have tried so far, but I'm not happy about it. I'm sure there's much better approach for this kind of code.

```js
const inp = document.querySelectorAll("#choices input");
const inpCorrect = document.querySelector("#correct");
inp.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener("click", function () {
     inpCorrect.value = this.value;
  })
  x.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
     inpCorrect.value = this.value;
    this.value == inpCorrect.value ? this.style.border = '2px solid green' : this.style.border = '2px solid black';
  })
})
```

```css
#choices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  gap: 20px;
}
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="choices">
  <div><label for="correct">Choices A:</label>
<input type="text" id="choicesA"></div>
    <div><label for="correct">Choices B:</label>
<input type="text" id="choicesB"></div>
    <div><label for="correct">Choices C:</label>
<input type="text" id="choicesC"></div>
    <div><label for="correct">Choices D:</label>
<input type="text" id="choicesD"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<label for="correct">Correct Answer:</label>
<input type="text" id="correct">
```

Comment: Pls add more details, are you trying to make MCQ type

Comment: Please add sample choices and correct answers

Comment: Yes i'm doing MCQ. I wan't to change the color border of choices inputs if the value is equal to correct input and make other border color black, also my code is not so good i think there is a better way to make it much more clean and optimize? i'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with this code.

First: by assigning `inpCorrect.value = this.value;` you are ensuring that the value of the "correct" input will be *changed* every time any input receives a keyup or click event. If you are always changing the "correct" value to match the current value, then the current value will always seem correct. I am not really sure what you are going for with setting this, so I have removed those lines.

Second: It's not really a good idea to do assignment in a ternary (`x = something ? foo : bar`) conditional expression. Expressions like these should evaluate to a result, and not execute side effects.

Is this closer to the behavior you're looking for?

```js
const inp = document.querySelectorAll("#choices input");
const inpCorrect = document.querySelector("#correct");
inp.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    if (this.value == inpCorrect.value) {
      this.style.border = '2px solid green';
    } else {
      this.style.border = '2px solid black';
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#choices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  gap: 20px;
}
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="choices">
  <div><label for="correct">Choices A:</label>
<input type="text" id="choicesA"></div>
    <div><label for="correct">Choices B:</label>
<input type="text" id="choicesB"></div>
    <div><label for="correct">Choices C:</label>
<input type="text" id="choicesC"></div>
    <div><label for="correct">Choices D:</label>
<input type="text" id="choicesD"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<label for="correct">Correct Answer:</label>
<input type="text" id="correct">
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what you mean. Typically multiple choice questions are answered by selecting one of the given answers, not by typing an answer.

Here's a snippet for a multiple choice question, maybe that helps? It uses [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to retain the values, [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for the handler and some css for the styling.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`choice`)) {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.choice`).forEach(choice => 
      choice.classList.remove(`correct`, `incorrect`));
    const valueElem = evt.target.closest(`[data-value]`);
    
    if (valueElem.dataset.value === document.querySelector(`#correct`).value) {
      return valueElem.classList.add(`correct`);
    }
    
    return valueElem.classList.add(`incorrect`);
  }
}
```

```css
#choices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 25vw;
  gap: 5;
}  

[data-question]:before {
  content: attr(data-question);
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
  width: 80vw;
}

.choice {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 3px;
}

.choice.correct {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.choice.incorrect {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="choices" data-question="How many items do we find in a dozen?">
  <div class="choice" data-value="144">A. 144</span></div>
  <div class="choice" data-value="12">B. 12</span></div>
  <div class="choice" data-value="24">C. 24</span></div>
  <div class="choice" data-value="33">D. 33</span></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="correct" value="12">
</div>
```

**After your comments**: loop the relevant input elements, compare them to the given correct value and colorize the border if the input value matches the correct value.

Play with this code @[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mjwanp?file=index.html)

```js
document.addEventListener(`keyup`, handle);

function markCorrect(correctAnswer) {
  const correct = value => value !== `` && value === correctAnswer;
  document.querySelectorAll(`[data-answer]`)
    .forEach(inp => correct(inp.value.trim()) ?
      inp.classList.add(`correct`) :
      inp.classList.remove(`correct`));
}

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.closest(`.choiceEdit`)) {
    return markCorrect(document.querySelector(`#correctAnswer`).value);
  }
}
```

```css
.inp {
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
}

.choice {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 3px;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}

input.correct {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="choices">
  <div class="inp">
    <input type="text" id="question" class="nocolor" value="How many is a dozen?"> The question
  </div>
  <div class="inp choiceEdit">
    <input type="text" id="correctAnswer" value="12"> The correct answer
  </div>
  <div class="inp choiceEdit">
    <input type="text" data-answer="a"> Answer A
  </div>
  <div class="inp choiceEdit">
    <input type="text" data-answer="b"> Answer B
  </div>
  <div class="inp choiceEdit">
    <input type="text" data-answer="c"> Answer C
  </div>
  <div class="inp choiceEdit">
    <input type="text" data-answer="d"> Answer D
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is empty because it is creating a questionnaire to be inserted into database.

Comment: So, you want to create an *editor* to *create* a MCQ?

Comment: Yes, sorry i can't explain it clearly. not fluent in english. i updated my question